# sklearn.SVR using multiple features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I've been away from sklearn for a while, and evidently forgot something key (and likely simple).  I want to fit a dataset of 6696 samples and four features: `X.shape` is (6696,1) and `y.shape` is (6696, 4).  But the `regressor.fit()` function is complaining about the y array -- what am I missing?

```
>>> X
array([[ 50.],
       [ 50.],
       [ 50.],
       ...,
       [750.],
       [750.],
       [750.]])
>>> y
array([[ 7776., 13364.,  3468., 29436.],
       [ 7156., 13780.,  3480., 29264.],
       [ 6924., 12444.,  3636., 29152.],
       ...,
       [27404., 27764., 18136., 31328.],
       [25896., 27580., 12696., 31480.],
       [21892., 18540.,  5000., 31656.]])
>>> regressor = SVR(kernel='rbf')
>>> regressor.fit(X, y)
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (6696, 4) instead.
```

(P.S.: yes, as soon as I get this part working, I'll use `StandardScaler()` to normalize the features.)

Answer (score 0):

Doh.  Solved.  I was mixing up X and y.  The working solution (note that y must be a 1d array, not a column):

```
>>> y.ravel()
array([ 50.,  50.,  50., ..., 750., 750., 750.])
>>> X
array([[ 7776., 13364.,  3468., 29436.],
       [ 7156., 13780.,  3480., 29264.],
       [ 6924., 12444.,  3636., 29152.],
       ...,
       [27404., 27764., 18136., 31328.],
       [25896., 27580., 12696., 31480.],
       [21892., 18540.,  5000., 31656.]])
>>> regressor = SVR(kernel='rbf')
>>> regressor.fit(X, y)
SVR()
```